# Disabled Facebook Login iOS throws com.facebook.sdk.core Code=8

Tags: ios, facebook-login

Our App was disabled a week ago due to violation on 6.1 and we tried to fix the issue
I have tried reimplementing the login following the instructions on the Facebook login setup guide. Also tried updating from 9.0.1 to the latest version 12.1.0

I can confirm that the info.plist is correct, the permissions are correct, bundle id is correct, and we only use test accounts.

However this error still throws, I could not find any references to fix this.
Could anyone help?

Don't know if this helps but the android app using version 5.4.0 build is working fine

```
Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.core Code=8 "(null)" UserInfo={NSRecoveryAttempter=<_FBSDKTemporaryErrorRecoveryAttempter: 0x1630097f0>, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=The server is temporarily busy, please try again., com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorDeveloperMessageKey=Unsupported request, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorHTTPStatusCodeKey=400, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorGraphErrorCodeKey=1, NSLocalizedRecoveryOptions=(
    OK
), com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorParsedJSONResponseKey={
    body =     {
        error =         {
            code = 1;
            "fbtrace_id" = ANc5PSXRGPTACuYqqxYTDda;
            message = "Unsupported request";
            type = OAuthException;
        };
    };
    code = 400;
}, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorKey=1}
```

Comment: I am facing the same problem on an app, disabled for the same reason, and the iOS login throws the same error.

Answer (score 0):

From your error response, it seems like you are requesting data from a not-existing API or that your token is invalid

> error =         {
> code = 1;
> "fbtrace_id" = ANc5PSXRGPTACuYqqxYTDda;
> message = "Unsupported request";
> type = OAuthException;
> };

**from Facebook's docs:** [OAuthException | code= 1](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/guides/error-handling)

//API Unknown//

Possibly a temporary issue due to downtime. Wait and retry the operation. If it occurs again, check that you are requesting an existing API.